# TikZ Layer Invisible

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to place an image in the background using TikZ layers but as soon as I enable the layers option, everything in the background layer disappears. I have no idea why. I found some hints about the main layer but this problem seems to be with the background layer. I also tried the `backgrounds` library. Same problem. (I've had success with layers on this same machine before but I'm no expert.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,fit} 


\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\tikzstyle{userblock}=[draw,rectangle,fill=gray!15,minimum height=4em,minimum width=4em, node distance=6em];    

\tikzstyle{tasklabels}=[node distance=5em];  
\tikzstyle{compblock}=[draw=blue, fill=blue!15,node distance=5em, minimum height=4em, minimum width=20em, inner sep=1em];      


\node[userblock]                (u1)    {user$_1$} ; 
\node[userblock,right of=u1]    (u2)    {user$_2$} ;
\node[userblock, draw=none,fill=none,right of=u2]   (udots) {\ldots} ;
\node[userblock,right of=udots] (un)    {user$_n$} ;


\node[tasklabels,below of=u1]               (l1)    {compiler} 
    edge [<->] (u1); 
\node[tasklabels, below of=u2]              (l2)    {assembler}
    edge [<->] (u2) ;   
\node[tasklabels, below of=udots]           (ldots)     {...}
;   
\node[tasklabels, below of=un]              (ln)    {database system}
    edge [<->] (un) ;   

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[compblock,fit=(l1)(ln)]               (L1)    {System and Application Programs}
    edge [-,dashed] (l1) 
    edge [-,dashed] (l2) 
    edge [-,dashed] (ln)  ;
\node[compblock,below of=L1]  (L2) {Operating System}
    edge [<->] (L1) ;
\node[compblock,below of=L2]  (L3) {Computer Hardware}
    edge [<->] (L2) ;
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\usetikzlibrary` and declare and set the layers before you start the `tikzpicture` environment. When I did this, the missing nodes and edges appeared.

You could move also `\tikzstyle`, but here it would be better to use `\tikzset` instead, or to give the styles as option to the `tikzpicture` environment.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  userblock/.style={draw,rectangle,fill=gray!15,minimum height=4em,
    minimum width=4em, node distance=6em},
  tasklabels/.style={node distance=5em]}, 
  compblock/.style={draw=blue, fill=blue!15,node distance=5em,
    minimum height=4em, minimum width=20em, inner sep=1em}]
...
```

Comment: So, simply moving the `usetikzlibrary` out of the `tikzpicture` environment solved it.